# Camera logic WPF (Binding Properties)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, camera

I'm currently trying to implement some kind of camera-logic for a schoolproject( 2D Multiplayer-PacMan) using WPF(first time im using wpf). We have a Tile-Based Walkmap using a Canvas and an ItemControl, which is bigger than the actual screensize:

**GameView.xaml**

```
<controls:Camera HorizontalOffset="{Binding xPos}" VerticalOffset="{Binding yPos}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="{Binding Size}" Height="{Binding Size}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
</controls:Camera>
```

I'm trying to use a ScrollViewer for my Camera, but as you all know we can't bind The Horizontal and Vertical Offset to Properties due to the fact that they are readonly.
Thats why I created a UserControl named "Camera" which has a ScrollViewer and two DependencyProperties for Binding.

**Camera.xaml**

```
        <UserControl x:Class="PacmanClient.UserControls.Camera"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PacmanClient.UserControls"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="1600" d:DesignWidth="1900">
        <UserControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
                <ScrollViewer Name="cameraViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsEnabled="True">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </UserControl.Template>
    </UserControl>
```

**Camera.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Camera : UserControl
{
    ScrollViewer cameraViewer;
    public Camera()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region HorizontalOffset

    public override void  OnApplyTemplate()
    {


        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        cameraViewer = this.Template.FindName("cameraViewer", this) as ScrollViewer;
    } 

    public double HorizontalOffset
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
            OnHorizontalOffsetChanged(value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(Camera),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));


    private void OnHorizontalOffsetChanged(double value)
    {
        cameraViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(value);
    }

    #endregion



    #region VerticalOffset


    public double VerticalOffset
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
            OnVerticalOffsetChanged(value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(Camera),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));


    private void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(double value)
    {
        cameraViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(value);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Now I'm having two problems.
First:
When im trying to use my UserControl(as seen in GameView.xaml) and bind some Properties to the DependencyProperties, I'm getting the Error that those members are not recognized or accessible.( I actually thought i fixed this, but now it's back.) This has to be an AccessProblem, because autocompletion actually suggests me HorinzontalOffset and VerticalOffset.
I just can't find a solution.

And Second:
In the Version where I was able to access those Properties and successfully bind some Properties to them, the Values of the DependencyProperties never changed when the properties bound to them changed. I checked it via debugging and the setter of the code behind property is never called.

I'm hoping you can help me with those problems, i have no idea why it isn't working.

**[Edit]**

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1600" Width="1900">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="yolo" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <ScrollViewer Name ="hallo" Height="1600" Width="1600" test:ScrollViewerExtension.HorizontalOffset = "{Binding xPos}" test:ScrollViewerExtension.VerticalOffset="{Binding yPos}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Canvas Height="3000" Width="3000">
                <Ellipse Name="e1" Height="42" Width="42" Fill="Yellow"></Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Mainwindow.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double xPos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double yPos
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            xPos += 50.0;
            yPos += 50.0;
            Canvas.SetTop(e1, yPos);
            Canvas.SetLeft(e1, xPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you craete custom control, you should create DependencyProperty. You created AttachedProperty, that's something else.

I will show you, how to use attached property:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" Height="100" Width="150"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              local:ScrollViewerExtension.HorizontalOffset="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1}">
    <Rectangle Height="80" Width="100" Margin="100,50,0,0" Fill="Red"/>
</ScrollViewer>

<!-- you can databind ScrollViewerExtension.HorizontalOffset to whatever, 
     Slider is just for demonstration purposes -->

<Slider x:Name="Slider1" 
        Maximum="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewer1, Path=ScrollableWidth}" />
```

and the attached property definition:

```
public static class ScrollViewerExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalOffset", typeof (double), typeof (ScrollViewerExtension),
        new PropertyMetadata(HorizontalOffsetChanged));

    private static void HorizontalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer) d;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
    }

    public static void SetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double) element.GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty);
    }
}
```

as you can see, attached properties should be used with existing controls. If you create new control, use dependency properties

Comment: Well  I made a testproject and bound a double Property which is in codebehind of mainwindow to local:scrollviewerextension:horizontaloffset but the dependenyproperty is never updated and the scrollviewer isnt scrolling on its own...

Comment: You did something wrong, because I copied&pasted this code from working demo.

Comment: you can see my testcode in the Edit... i took your scrollviewer extension class for testingpurposes

Comment: Ok, I see two problems in you code. First, you are not binding to xPos, resp yPos, as you may expect. Bindings in wpf binds to object present in element's DataContext by default. Your DataContext is probably null (from wha I can see in the example). Either specify set window to the datacontext, or use relativesource. Second, you need to call PropertyChanged event in the property setter. Bindings listens to the event and updates only when the event is called. Just google for INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see if this helps you. Your first problem is difficult to solve without seeing your full code, because what you have shown here does not have any problem (in fact, i made a test solution copying/pasting this code and it worked). 
The second problem has to do with how you have defined the attached properties.
In the third parameter of RegisterAttached you should add a callback to your propertyChanged event handling method, like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalOffset", typeof(object), typeof(Camera),new UIPropertyMetadata(null, HorizontalOffsetPropertyChanged));
```

Also you need to add two methods for getting/setting this property value:

```
public static object GetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
    }
```

This is the full code for your usercontrol:

```
public partial class Camera : UserControl
{
    public Camera()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region HorizontalOffset

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalOffset", typeof(object), typeof(Camera),new UIPropertyMetadata(null, HorizontalOffsetPropertyChanged));

    public static object GetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
    }

    public static void HorizontalOffsetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Camera cam = o as Camera;
        ScrollViewer scroll=cam.Template.FindName("cameraViewer", cam) as ScrollViewer;
        double horizontal = 0;
        if (e.NewValue is double)
        {
            horizontal =(double) e.NewValue;
        }
        scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(horizontal);
    }

    #endregion



    #region VerticalOffset


    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset", typeof(object), typeof(Camera), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, VerticalOffsetPropertyChanged));

    public static object GetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
    }

    public static void SetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
    }

    public static void VerticalOffsetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Camera cam = o as Camera;
        ScrollViewer scroll = cam.Template.FindName("cameraViewer", cam) as ScrollViewer;
        double vertical = 0;
        if (e.NewValue is double)
        {
            vertical = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
        scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(vertical);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Hope this gets you on the track